# How to resolve "can not find chromedriver for currently installed chrome version"?

Tags: python, google-chrome

When I run my Python script I get the following warning:

```
WARNING:root:Can not find chromedriver for currently installed chrome version.
```

How can I resolve this issue? I have tried installing `request` and checked the versions.

Comment: Not sure why this is a VS code issue, but check if your Chrome driver version is compatible with your Chrome broswer version

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can not find chromedriver for currently installed chrome version

Your version of Chrome and Chromedriver has to be the same. I suggest you turning on automatic updates for Chrome, and downloading the newest version of chromedriver.

You can use the command `pip install webdriver-manager` to install `webdriver-manager`. Then run the following codes to download the chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

You can also download from [this page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 115 successfully using version 0.6.2 on Win32.
please use the latest version using:

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller==0.6.2
```

OR

You could use the below code for the 114++ Chrome version!
I'm using it it working perfectly for now!

selenium 4

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.16").install()),options=option)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code for the 114++ Chrome version!
I'm using it it working perfectly for now!

selenium 4

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.16").install()),options=option)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```